# The flower and worker is not acessible in ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose, airflow, flower

I have docker-compose.yml to create my airflow environment. I tested in my local machine and everything is ok, but when I put on ec2, the flower and works logs is not acessible.

I already able the ports 5555 and 8793 in security groups, but isn't work.

Comment: Anybody help me ?

Comment: *** Log file does not exist: /app/airflow/airflow/logs/s3_FW/s3-fw/2020-10-13T03:16:09.963249+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://worker_host:8888/log/s3_FW/s3-fw/2020-10-13T03:16:09.963249+00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. 502 Server Error: notresolvable for url: http://worker_host:8888/log/s3_FW/s3-fw/2020-10-13T03:16:09.963249+00:00/1.log